# How to set Angular Activated Route Param

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I realize this is not a typical use case but I'm looking for a way to set Angular's Activated Route param. I want to be able to do something like the following in a component...

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(param => param.id = 'mySetId');
```

Then I might run some other methods on the component and then run getId() in a routing service to get the setId set from the component...

```
public getId(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  let id;
  route.params.subscribe(param => id = param.id);

  return id;
}
```

getId() would then return 'mySetId'

Any ideas?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to set the `ActivatedRoute`'s params is by making the `Router` `navigate` to the same route, but with different params.

So basically if you want to set a new `param` you can simply use the `Router` and call the `navigate` method on it and pass it a new `param`.

The new param can then be obtained by again injecting the `ActivatedRoute` as a dependency and then retrieving it by `subscribe`ing to the `params` `Observable`.